# Animations on action buttons as a progress indicator

Tags: mobile, actions

Are there examples of using animations on actions buttons to indicate that the action triggered by the user is in progress? Is it better to apply a modal or lightbox effect to block out other actions if the user can't do anything else anyway, or could this be an acceptable approach for devices with smaller viewing space (e.g. mobile phones).

Answer (score 3):

[Are there examples of progress buttons you say. Indeed there are. You'll definitely like this.](http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/)

If other action buttons exist on the page that will cancel out the active action, but are not cancel buttons, I would say yes, [disable them](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_disabled). But if there is a specific action button, a cancel button, that is meant to cancel the action in progress, than I wouldn't disable them.

Comment: A very interesting link, but I wonder if it is just doing too much when it is better to keep things nice and simple. Also, would it really be more restricted to the desktop or tablet space rather than on mobile phones or apps?

Comment: Animations help users understand the process. When submitting a form, no animation or no specific 'success-message' will leave the user wondering if their submission was successful. A small animation on the submit button, as seen in the link, will allow you to convey the 'success-message' to the user while staying on the same page (because success messages often force you to remove the form and to change the page in order to display the message) (it's also a nice alternative to alert messages). In that case, an animation on a button **is nice and simple** and IMO usable for desktop and mobile